# Histogram in a loop: Leave page blank when no data is found

Tags: r

I am printing a number of histograms in a loop. However when no data is found hist() gives an error "invalid number of 'breaks" and the program terminates. Is there any way I can leave the page blank when no data is found.

Here is  a sample part of the code I currently have

```
    par(mfrow=c(4,1))
    hist(data1,col="blue")
    hist(data2,col="blue")
    hist(data3,col="blue")
    hist(data4,col="blue")
    mtext(paste(title, "Speed Plot", sep=''),outer=TRUE)
```

Appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Where is the `loop` here?

Comment: What error message does it return?  What do you mean by "no data found" ?  That is: is there, e.g., an object `data3` which is empty, or is there no such object `data3` ?  In the latter case, why are you writing code like that?  And in any case, please rewrite your code in a loop. Maybe `all_data<-ls(pattern='data[0-9]') ; for (j in 1:length(all_data) hist(eval(as.name(all_data[[j]])),col='blue')` which has the added advantage of not trying to find nonexistent objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the function in `try`

`try(hist(data1, col="blue"))`

To explicitly create a blank plot, you can use `tryCatch`

```
tryCatch(hist(data1, col="blue"), error=function(e) plot.new())
```

Comment: For some reason rCatch() does not work, it gives me the same error as "invalid number of 'breaks". Do I need to use both try and tryCatch subsequently for each plot

Comment: Apologies for the typo tryCatch()

Comment: You need to use `try` or `tryCatch` for each function that may output an error. The error message will still display, but the loop will continue to run.

Comment: You are right. Got this to work! Used try(). tryCatch() was making blank pages for all remaining plots from where it found an error.